# Saving videos to photo library when taken from camera in IPhone

Tags: iphone, video, save

I was wondering if there is a method similar to  UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(UIImage *image, id completionTarget, SEL completionSelector, void *contextInfo), that saves Videos taken from the iphone camera  to the u sers Photo Albums... been trying to look  for it in apple docs but havent found anything.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After digging around: The answer is there is no such feature in SDK 3.0, however it is coming in 3.1, the method is void UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum (
   NSString  *videoPath,
   id        completionTarget,
   SEL       completionSelector,
   void      *contextInfo
);, heres a link 
http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIKitFunctionReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum

Answer (score 0):

I too was looking forward to the ability to save videos to the camera roll... but now that 3.1 is out, I still haven't found a way to do it.

Maybe what they were referring to was the ability to save videos received in emails and SMS messages to the camera roll (which ARE new features in the 3.1 OS).  The only new class related to video that I've seen is the UIVideoEditorController (http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIVideoEditorController_ClassReference/Reference/Reference.html), and there are some new properties for UIImagePickerController that let you specify max video duration, and video quality... but I still haven't found anything that lets you save videos to the camera roll.

Has anyone else figured this out?

Comment: its there check it out http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIKitFunctionReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum