# Getting photo and video file path and storing into the sqlite

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sqlite

I am trying to the photo and video file path and storing into the sqlite.
I am getting photo like this but I want know how i get the file path And store that into the sqlite And the same thing is i need with video alsoIs that possible to do that or is that any other idea or hints to solve that

```
-(IBAction) getPhoto:(id) sender {
    UIImagePickerController * UIPicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    UIPicker.delegate = self;



    if([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary])
    {


        UIPicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
        [self presentModalViewController:UIPicker animated:YES];
    }
    else {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:nil message:@"Error" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
        [alert release];
    }
}


- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {


    [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    imageView.image = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];
}
```

I thing people will help me out 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(sample);
NSData *myImage=[[NSData alloc]initWithData:imageData];
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *fullPathToFile = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Image%d.png",i]];
[myImage writeToFile:fullPathToFile atomically:YES];
[myImage release];
```

Hope this code helps.
Where i is an integer which can take any values 1,2,3....
increment i each time to avoid overwriting images.Now u can store many images without any overwrite problems.If u want to keep storing different images even after the application is closed you can use the NSUSerDefaults to store the last value of i.

```
NSString *myImage=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Image%d",i];
```

After this increase the i value by 1. Then use the myImage string to store it in the sqlite database. Hope this helps.

[Link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1159516/saving-videos-to-photo-library-when-taken-from-camera-in-iphone)
[Link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5288840/iphone-imagepickercontroller-picking-video-from-photo-library)

Comment: it will store the photo in DocumentsDirectory what it is [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Image.png"] I didn't get you .Can you explain me more about the @"Image.png".

Comment: It is just the name of the image file. I am passing it to the stringByAppendingPathComponent after making it into a formatted string. I have edited the answer now.If u want u can ignore the format option and give the @"image.png" filename directly. Hope u got me now.

Comment: this is where i get the photo imageView.image = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"]; "imageView.image" is my UIImageView *imageView .can i use the imageView replace with Image.png

Comment: No.... image.png is the file name. There u are naming the file b4 saving it to the documents folder.It must be a string. You cant pass an UIImageView object to it.

Comment: I get confused .Can you explain me more

Comment: There is nothing to get confused here. It s pretty simple. You are specifying the filename for your image b4 saving it to the docs folder. Or else just tell me clearly what u dont understand ? Let me try to explain it

Comment: I am doing like this it just simple to pick image and display on the imageView Which the the UIImageView Object [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    imageView.image = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];   is that directly i use your code for storing the image in the DocumentsDirectory or  I have do something else .if i am not wrong.

Comment: I thing it must like this  NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(self.imageView.image);  than after word your rest of code i thing so .IS that right .

Comment: But one problem is that it store only one image NSString *fullPathToFile = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Image.png"]]; I think get overwrite again -again How can i solve  that

Comment: Than how can we store that file path location into the sqlite database

Comment: @Shima let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1651/discussion-between-iphonefreak-and-shima)

Comment: I accept your answer but it not give any link for the video storing in db

Comment: Check the links I have posted below the answer.It might help

Answer (score 0):

Check UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL in the [UIImagePickerControllerDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImagePickerControllerDelegate_Protocol/UIImagePickerControllerDelegate/UIImagePickerControllerDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UIImagePickerControllerDelegate).

That will give the file path.

But I recommend store that image in some other place using NSFileManager and store that file path in your sqlite since the image might be deleted by some other ways.

Answer (score 0):

You need to store image into documents directory using NSFileManager. Search on google or stackoverflow you will find many tutorials. Then you store that path into sqlite that's it. I suggest you to use Unique identifier for each image you can find that code snippet too on goole or stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSArray *sysPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask,YES);
NSString *docDirectory = [sysPaths objectAtIndex:0];


    NSString *filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", docDirectory,@"ImageName.png"];
    awesomeView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10,60,60 )];
    awesomeView.image =[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
    [mainView addSubview:awesomeView];
    [awesomeView release];
```

You can use this code to retrieve the image from documents folder and display it in the UIImageView. You can simply store the name of the file alone in sqlite . Using that u can replace the @"image.png" with the fileName retrieved from the database. Hope this helps.

Comment: I do like this  NSString *fullPathToFile = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.png",camtitle.text]];
But when how can get this for displaying it